# Make outputs incoherent error messages

Tags: gcc, makefile, arm, gnu

I am using Make 3.8.1 in Windows and I am trying to compile a project provided by Nordic Semi using their own makefile. However, I do not know the problem as make is not clear in what it is trying to say. Below is the error message I get after inputting `make -j`:

```
rm -rf _build
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -rf _build, ...) failed.
make: *** `nrf52832_xxaa_s132' ?E?K?v?E?^?[?Q?b?g `_build/Arkan' ?d make ?・? 
e???[???a???e?U?1?n.  ’†?~.
make: *** ?￠?R?1?I?W?‡?u?d‘O?A?A?￠?U?・....
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [clean] ?G?‰?[ 2
```

I suspect this is not Nordic's fault, and so I reinstalled Make multiple times. Unfortunately, I still get the same exact error message. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: First, try running `make` in single job mode.  So just `make` *without* the `-j` flag.

Comment: Follow what you said, I got `rm -rf _build
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -rf _build, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [clean] ?G?‰?[ 2`. While this looks much cleaner, the last line still looks iffy.

Comment: Which kind of make is this? Can't you just install Cygwin with a more recent version?

Answer (score 0):

The version of GNU make you're using is 3.81, not 3.8.1 (there is no 3.8.1).  That's a very old version (released in 2006) so there's little chance of getting much support with it.  You can get newer versions either to build yourself (at https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make ) or pre-built for Windows (at various places; the best one is https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/ )

I can't explain why you're seeing corrupted error messages with your version.  However, the command "rm -rf" is a POSIX command and there is no "rm" command available on Windows by default, which is probably why make is failing to run it.  I suspect that this project you're attempting to build was created for POSIX systems such as GNU/Linux or MacOS and was not intended to be built on Windows, at least not unless some POSIX compatibility layer is installed, such as cygwin or mingw32.